# Quotient Topology, equivalence relation. I need help to prove if X is homeomorphic to X/~

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

> Let $X = [0,3] \subset\mathbb{R}$ and consider the following equivalence relation:
>   $$ x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x=y \vee x,y \in [1,2]$$
>   and call $Y = X/\sim$.
>
> **(1).** Establish if $Y$ is connected, compact, Hausdorff.
>
> **(2).** Establish if X is homeomorphic to Y.

*Proof*.

For the point (1), I know that $Y$ is connected, compact because $X$ is compact and connected and

$$\pi:X\rightarrow\mathit(X/\sim)$$

is continuous and surjective.

I think that $Y$ is also Hausdorff because if

$x$, $y\in [0,1)\cup(2,3]$

$X$ is Hausdorff, so I can find $\mathcal{U}_{x}$, $\mathcal{U}_{y}$ such that $\mathcal{U}_{x}\cap\mathcal{U}_{y}=\emptyset$.

Now I can choose

$\mathcal{V}_{x}=\pi(\mathcal{U}_{x}\cap(X\setminus[1,2])$

$\mathcal{V}_{y}=\pi(\mathcal{U}_{y}\cap(X\setminus[1,2])$.

If $x\in[0,1)\cup(2,3]$ and $y\in[1,2]$ I can choose

$\mathcal{U}_{x}$, $\mathcal{U}_{1}$ disjointed

$\mathcal{U'}_{x}$, $\mathcal{U}_{2}$ disjointed too

Now I can choose

$\mathcal{V}_{x}=\pi(\mathcal{U}_{x}\cap\mathcal{U'}_{x})$

$\mathcal{V}_{y}=\pi(\mathcal{U}_{1}\cup\mathcal{U}_{2})$

If $y\in[0,1)\cup(2,3]$ and $x\in[1,2]$ I can do the same

If $x$, $y\in[1,2]$ we have that

$\pi(x)=\pi(y)$

So we have that for each $x$, $y\in Y$ I can find  $\mathcal{V}_{x}$, $\mathcal{V}_{y}$ open sets disjointed.

Now I don't know how to continue for the point (2).

Can someone help me?

Comment: You don’t want $(0,1)$ in your definition of $\mathscr{V}_y$, but otherwise it looks okay. For (2): can you see a way to show that $Y$ is homeomorphic to $[0,2]$; then you can find a homeomorphism from $[0,2]$ to $[0,3]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a mental image to help you understand what the homeomorphism should look like:

Since you identify the closed interval $[1,2]$, you can think about this as taking the interval $[0,3]$, and "squishing" its middle part (the interval $[0,2]$) into a single point. This basically leaves you with a "smaller" version of $[0,3]$, which is only of length $2$.

Can you think of some nice $f$ that will display the procedure of "squishing" the interval?

(A little tip - if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and bijective, $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is a homeomorphism. Meaning - you don't need to make sure that the inverse is continuous )

Comment: It's a good point of view. I think that a good example of this f is an Homothetic transformation, but onestly I don't know how I could define it...

Comment: The map should be "sort of" homothetic, but you also want it to respect the fact that all points in [1,2] are identified. Try thinking about the function given by Berci. While it is not injective on [0,3], it is injective (and well defined) on the quotient space!

Comment: Now you just need to use the fact that [0,2] is homeomorphic to [0,3] (by the usual homothetic transformation), and use the fact that being homeomorphic is an equivalence relation :)

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the continuous map $[0,3] \to [0,2]$
$$x\mapsto \left\{\matrix{x\ \text{ if }x<1 \\ 1\ \text{ if } x\in [1,2]\\ x-1\ \text{ if } x>2}\right.$$